# Laravel Collective date format

Tags: laravel, date, laravel-5.4, laravelcollective

Is there a way to set `Laravel Collective` date picker format to `yyyy-mm-dd`?

I am using now:

```
{{ Form::date('deadline', null,['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

but in the front end I get an input field with `mm/dd/yyyy` inside. I tried parsing the `Carbon` instance as second parameter, but that does nothing.

```
{{ Form::date('deadline', \Carbon\Carbon::now()->format('Y-m-d'),['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, Laravel Collective does not provide this option.

Use https://eonasdan.github.io/bootstrap-datetimepicker/

```
{{ Form::text('deadline', null, ['class' => 'form-control', 'id'=>'datetimepicker']) }}
```

Javascript

```
$('#datetimepicker').datetimepicker({
    format: 'yyyy-mm-dd'
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You could pass an `DateTime` instance for the second parameter. As per the [source code](https://github.com/LaravelCollective/html/blob/5.4/src/FormBuilder.php#L401) if the second parameter is an DateTime instance it  would return the formatted date `(Y-m-d)`.

So you could try this,

```
{{ Form::date('deadline', new \DateTime(), ['class' => 'form-control']) }}
```

Note:

As [@Ajahi himalil](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10021229/ajahi-himalil) stated in the comment, the value in the request would be different from the one selected. Please verify the data on form submission.

Comment: this will send the value as new current date not selected date . This is not the best method.

Answer (score 0):

After applying all these methods and nothing working. simple input tag with date type is the only solution that i came to know instead of collective laravel.